# Mac OS X Yosemite and Client SSL Certificates

Tags: python, ssl, curl, osx-yosemite, client-certificate

Ever since I upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite, my SSL Client Certificates have stopped working in certain places.  They still work in web browsers and in `wget`, but they have stopped working in `curl` and in Python's `requests` library.

This works:

```
$ wget https://localhost --certificate cert.pem --private-key private.pem
```

This doesn't work:

```
$ curl https://localhost --cert cert.pem --key private.pem
curl: (58) SSL: Can't load the certificate "cert.pem" and its private key: OSStatus -25299
```

But yet if I combine the pems into a p12, it does work:

```
$ curl https://localhost --cert cert.p12:password
```

But Python doesn't support p12s, and this doesn't work:

```
import requests
print requests.get("https://localhost", cert=("cert.pem","private.pem")).content
```

It doesn't complain, but it doesn't send the client certificate either.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
The new version of CURL uses Apple's Secure Transport API now instead of the OpenSSL API  and you'll need to use the P12 format for certificates.

See the write up here: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2013-10/0036.html